# Eclipse showing garbage file names

Tags: eclipse

All of a sudden, my eclipse has started showing the garbage names as the title of different file panels. It was working fine previously the other day, the only thing that I did after that was changing the workspace folder once to open a certain project. I had changed that to default value again.

The file names are getting shown correctly in the project explorer.

[image: Title of file panels]
[image: Project Explorer]

I tried to fnd the solution online but was unable to find the related issue. I apologize if it's not the appropriate way or question to be asked here.

Comment: It is an issue with the fonts on your system see [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=551965)

Comment: Since it attracted a downvote, Can anyone just let me know in the comments why it's not a proper way or why it should be here? I'll delete it and remember that thing next time while asking a question.

Comment: @greg-449 thanks I was able to solve the problem with that.